# SQL if-else equivalent in WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I have declared a variable 'LessThan' that can either be 0 or 1. Depending on that value, I need to show results that have Amount value less than 20 or greater than 20. Here is what I have so far:

```
WHERE (@ResidentID = ds.ResidentID OR @ResidentID IS NULL AND ds.Amount < 20)
```

What I want is to show results where ds.Amount is less than < 20 IF 'LessThan' has value = 0 and I want results where ds.Amount is greater than > 20 if 'LessThan' has value = 1.

I reckon this is easy but I never really worked with SQL before and I'm having syntax troubles.

Comment: Please specify database engine you're using in tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
where ((@isLessThan = 0 and amount > 20) or (@isLessThan = 1 and amount < 20))
```